# karma Test : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-runner, observable

I'm trying to test a ReactiveFormsControle with a separate formControle file dependency that contain the control form function. I need to use an observable to pass the form controls and returning messages errors after that. But when I tried to test that I have this error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Can any one help me please.

this is my code :

***This is how can I call the Form control function(process Message) :***

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
// Watch for the blur event from any input element on the form.
let controlBlurs: Observable<any>[] = this.formInputElements
  .map((formControl: ElementRef) => Observable.fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));
// Merge the blur event observable with the valueChanges observable
Observable.merge(this.signUpForm.valueChanges, ...controlBlurs).debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => {
  this.displayeErrorMessage = this.formValidator.processMessages(this.signUpForm);
});
```

}

***processMessage function:***

```
  processMessages(container : FormGroup) : {[key : string]: string}{

let messages = {};

for(let controlKey in container.controls){
  if(container.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlKey)){
    let c = container.controls[controlKey];

    if(c instanceof FormGroup){
      let childMessages = this.processMessages(c);
      Object.assign(messages, childMessages);
    }else {

      if(this.validationErrorMessages[controlKey]){
        messages[controlKey]='';
        if((c.dirty || c.touched) && c.errors){
          Object.keys(c.errors).map(messageKey =>{
            if(this.validationErrorMessages[controlKey][messageKey]){
              messages[controlKey] += this.validationErrorMessages[controlKey][messageKey] + ' '
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
return messages;
```

}

*** this the test code that handle the error ***

```
 beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignUpComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
debugHelpblck = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.help-block'));
component.ngOnInit();
component.ngAfterViewInit(); // this handle the error
fixture.detectChanges();
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Add `filter(Boolean)` before `map()`, or be more careful with your data (;

Not sure where your error appears, if this is all the code then:

```
let controlBlurs: Observable<any>[] = this.formInputElements
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(...)
```

or

```
Object.keys(c.errors).filter(Boolean).map(messageKey =>{...})
```

should fix the error...

Comment: thanks for your reply , karma chows this message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`  , I guess  the problem is that the Observable is not recognized by my spec file  but I don't know how can I fix this or declare the observable in the spec file.

Comment: Is `formInputElements` array or observable?

Comment: formInputElement is undefined and this is its declaration  : `@ViewChildren(FormControlName, {read: ElementRef}) formInputElements: ElementRef[];`

Comment: OK, you might have to use [`fakeAsync()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/fakeAsync-function.html) when testing forms. Wrap your `it()`s with it; not sure if it works with `beforeEach()`, so you might need to refactor your code...

Comment: But when I comment `component.ngAfterViewInit()` the test forms works well  but I need to test the error message that are hendled by processMessage function which is called in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Your `map` call maps every value to `undefined`. Also annotating the type of a local with `any` is there a band practice. Remove the type annotation altogether, it hides bugs.

Comment: Can you explain more please, what do yu mean by annotating the type of a local with any is there a band practice ?  after debugging the spec I find that the formInputElement is undefined